# Xiomi Note8 & Note5 postDelay Not Calling

Tags: android, handler

We are trying to call ***new Handler().postDelayed*** method in our app but Xiomi Note8 and Xiomi Note5 phones not calling this method. We tried to call this method also in Xiomi A3, Xiomi Mi Mix2 and Xiomi Mi 9se and didin't see any problem.

Handler from this package: android.os.Handler

Comment: This seems weird, Please provide a [mcve] .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `postDelayed()` in the worker thread on some devices.

Try `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());` and it should work.

Comment: Hi @Cullen. We tried it also. new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed() and also HandlerCompat().postDelayed() but result is same.